Kids' horror, with the bogey man?
This is one of the last things from my childhood that I haven't managed to determine the existence of.  It may be an amalgamation of memories from different shows, and it's possible that some of them are purely from my imagination.  That said:
I would like to identify a work that meets the following criteria:

Live action
It played on TV, or was available on VHS, between 1984 and 1990
The villain is the bogey man / boogie man / similar
The protagonist(s) are a child or children (I think it was a boy and girl?)
It included a father figure who did not believe in the threat of the bogey man
My strongest memory:  at one point, that father figure is levitated and spinning in the air, saying something like "boogey boogey boogey!  ...just kidding," which is probably a repetition of an earlier line teasing the protagonists
The bogey man was defeated by destroying a statue somehow bound to him.  That statue may have only been accessible by entering some other realm/dimension, which may have been accessed through a closet?
I think the haunting had something to do with a specific house?


Mr. Boogedy was awesome. He was like an evil Quaker version of Raiden from Mortal Kombat.

A lot of elements there sound similar to either Mr. Boogedy from 1986 or its sequel Bride of Boogedy from 1987. These Disney films both feature children battling the Boogeyman (their father initially doesn't believe them) and both end with a member of the family saying "Just kidding, just kidding" after a scare. But his source of power there is his cloak (although the sequel also involves a mystical cemetery statue, so it might be the better guess).  David Faustino (Bud from Married with Children) stars in both films as one of the children and the sequel also stars Eugene Levy, who's possessed by the cloak at some point.

Bridge of Boogedy looks like it's the one!  I guess my memory combined several of the levitation scenes starting around 50m; the one at about 57m30s has the line I remember.
I'll upvote once I have sufficient rep.

Thanks :) Glad you found it. Forgot to mention that the 1st one also stars Kristy Swanson from BtVS (the movie).

This is really only related by being another series that I thought I'd dreamed up, but the Walt Disney connection led me to finally find http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_100_Lives_of_Black_Jack_Savage.  I'd remembered the boat and some bare details of the plot (damned to hell unless they save lives).  Disney was putting out some weird stuff in the 80s and 90s!
